# How to Connect with SVN in Android Studio

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I am working with Android Studio and I have to connect my project with SVN. I've installed Subversion.

1. Subversion -> Update Directory,
2. Entered Url,
3. Username,
4. Password.

I'm not able to connect. I am new user of Android Studio and really need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MACOS**:

- install xcode

**WINDOWS**:

- You download [Apache-Subversion-1.8.10.zip](http://www.visualsvn.com/files/Apache-Subversion-1.8.10.zip). You will have a "bin" folder after unzip.
- Then you config your svn setting: specify command line client to svn.exe in the "bin" folder.
  [image]

**Share your project to svn**:
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to connect.

You can be unable to connect for a variety of reasons. There is no information in your question which will allow others to make any suggestions rather than ["read the manual"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/version-control-with-intellij-idea.html).

See [**"How do I ask a good question?**"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).